# how does one implement max(count(field_1)) in Hive?

Tags: hiveql

I have ran a query in Hive whose result gets me 2 columns (year and count).
1900 2
1901 5
1902 7
1903 3
1904 5

I need to find the maximum count and return both the year and the count; 
expecting answer 1902 7

I ran a nested query like in SQL but it gives me a parse error saying "..cannot recognize input 'select'in expression specification.."

Can anyone let me know? Thanks.

regards,
Rahul

Comment: Can you post your query?

Comment: I got it to run to a point where it does print 7 (from 1902). I need it to print both 1902 7. Here is my query: hive> select max(COL) from (select yearofpublication, count(booktitle) as COL from BXDataSet group by yearofpublication) a;

Comment: What is the expected output in the case when there are several years with the maximum count of book titles? For example, both 1900 and 1902 have 7 book titles.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `collect_max` UDF which returns the keys and values with the maximum values from Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse )

```
select collect_max( year, count , 1 ) 
  from mytable;
```

Or if you want separate columns

```
select array_index( map_keys( map_max ), 0 ) as max_year,
       array_index( map_values( map_max ), 0 ) as max_value
from 
  ( select collect_max( year, count, 1 ) from mytable );
```

Comment: Thanks, Jerome. I am new to UDFs etc. I will read about them and then implement your suggestion. Will let you know how I fared. Thanks.regards,Rahul

Comment: OK, so read a bit about UDFs. Now I have downloaded brickhouse-0.6.0.jar. I put that file in the folder /usr/lib/hive/aux-lib. Now I guess I should do hive> add jar /usr/lib/hive/aux-lib/brickhouse-0.6.0.jar; is that correct? and then hive> create temporary function collect_max as '"what exactly do i put here?" Thanks.

Comment: There is a resource file "brickhouse.hql" at https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/blob/master/src/main/resources/brickhouse.hql you can download, and then 'source' in the Hive CLI, or add the statement 'CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect_max AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectMaxUDAF';' in your Hive script

Comment: I could run collect_max function but it gives me "FAILED: Execution error Return code 2 from org....". So I checked the JobTracker Status Web dashboard for the Failed Job and upon clicking on it, found out that it is giving a runtime exception on the row which has the highest count (1902 7) from my above-stated example. Any idea what could be happening here? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace ? I'll file a JIRA
Also, we assume the key is a string, and the value is a double. Cast to those types if they aren't

Comment: Jerome, that worked ! Thanks. My key was string but the value was BigInt. I cast the value to double and that worked. Thanks, once again.

Comment: brickhouse udfs could really be useful..Where can I get a list of all brickhouse udfs? Also, is there an examples file that shows how those udfs are used etc.? Thanks.

Comment: Check out the wiki https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki and the blog http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/